# copy multiple columns from one sheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I have a time sheet for my workers who log their time using the sheet having below order

```
   Categories   Washing Cleaning   Office   Duties   Baking Cooking

Date          Hours  Hours     Hours    Hours     Hours Hours
Jan/1/13              3.00              6.00
Jan/2/13                        
Jan/6/13                        3.00    
Jan/10/13
```

Basically what I want is to have a code which copy dates with number of hours according to related category to another sheet called Report. I need three columns as output Date Hours Category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code :

```
Sub sample()


    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim col As Long
    Dim a As String, b As String, c As String

    With Sheets("sheet1")
        lastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        If lastRow < 4 Then lastRow = 4

        For i = 4 To lastRow
            For col = 2 To 7
                If .Cells(i, col) <> "" Then

                    a = .Cells(i, 1)
                    b = .Cells(i, col)
                    c = .Cells(1, col)

                    With Sheets("Report")
                        .Range("A" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = a
                        .Range("B" & .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = b
                        .Range("C" & .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = c
                    End With
                End If
            Next
        Next

    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Santosh, Thank you very much for such a great solution. Really I can't find words to thank you. I just have one more thing, as I have got more than one worker for instance lets say Sheet1 represents John, Sheet2 represents Michael and Sheet3 represents Tom and I want to have all workers details, how should I repeat the code for other workers so that I can get the data in one sheet.

Comment: @OMK28 `Dim sht As Worksheet
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        With sht
        
        'code
        '
        '
         End With
    Next` You can loop sheets using above code. Very Welcome :)

Comment: highly appreciate your help, actually I am a beginner and knows a very little about VBA, so it would be great if you can tell where and how to put these lines in the above code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
Sheet2.Range("A1").Value = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value
```

or

```
Sheet2.Range("A1").Text = Sheet1.Range("A1").Text
```

Maybe you could make a loop and do something like:

```
Sheet2.Range("A" & i).Value = Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value
```

There're a lot of options available to do this... even Range.Copy (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760.aspx)

Good luck.